# How to run a file using sudo bash as root

Tags: bash

I'm logging into a linux server that I don't own by using a `pem / ppk` file on PUTTY and the default user is `ubuntu`. Works great.

Problem now is that I want to run a script using admin `sudo bash start-work.sh` but it can't execute line 25 because only `start-work.sh` is being run as admin, not the content

> start-work.sh: line 25: /home/ubuntu/flowable/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: Permission denied

If I try `su -` I get asked a password but I have a `pem / ppk file`

What do I do?

Comment: `because only start-work.sh is being run as admin, not the content` I do not understand that part. How do you know that? What is the difference between running "only script as admin" versus "only running script content as admin"? That's equivalent. `start-work.sh: line 25` so what is the reason of permission denied? What is on line `25`?  Does the file `catalina.sh` is executable? Is it on a network drive, like NFS?

Comment: If a process is root, everything it starts is also root unless that thing actively goes out of its way to drop privileges.

Comment: Anyhow -- instead of requiring people to have a `start-work.sh` that nobody but you has, can you build a [mre] that anyone else can run to see the problem themselves?

Comment: And show `ls -al /home/ubuntu/flowable/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script `start-work.sh`, running as root, attempts to invoke another script `/home/ubuntu/flowable/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh`.

The error "Permission denied" indicates either:

1. `catalina.sh` is not executable, or
2. one or more directories in the path are not accessible by root

(1) can be fixed by `chmod +x` or similar

(2) can be caused in various ways, such as if the script is on an NFS filesystem mounted with `root_squash`, or on an sshfs FUSE filesystem mounted without `allow_root`.